# Replace values from column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Inside my Pandas dataframe, my 'Date' columns have strings of the format `mm/dd/yyyy`. What I want to do is convert them into `YYYY-dd-mm`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=1)

date_list = df['Date'].values
for item in date_list:
    item = pd.to_datetime(item).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print(item)
```

This code converts the dates successfully, but the dataframe is not changed. How can I make it change the dataframe with the new format?

Answer (score 2):

Better here is use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with all column values and then [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with change format to `%Y-%d-%m`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%d-%m')
```